# mysql. I want to replace the names of a some values in a column

Tags: mysql, sql, updating

I have a question for you. I have two columns that returns the duo of countries for electricity exchange.
the values look something like this:

```
**Area_in**         IT-NORTH-FR 
**Area_out**        IT-NORTH-AT
```

and there are many more values with IT-north-and(Germany for example)

I need a way of altering the values in both columns so that when these areas appear, only the name “IT-NORTH” gets returned

I don't want to create a new column by using case function. just updating the name. how can it be done

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
update yourtable set Area_in='IT-NORTH' where left(Area_in,8)='IT-NORTH'
update yourtable set Area_out='IT-NORTH' where left(Area_out,8)='IT-NORTH'
```

However, this will create duplicates if you have several rows of one column having 2+ it-north variants with the other col having the same value.